# Can gauge theory be explained completely non-relativistically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, charge, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I have been reading in the book: "[Particles, fields and forces - a conceptual guide to quantum field theory and the standard model](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-12878-4)". The specific chapter I have been reading you can find here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mCagtJgISrC6gneZ_IvBdFbl1KlWvR6B/view?usp=sharing

Here, they write about a phase-shift that occurs in the wave function of charged particles, because of the symmetry of a circle. And then this phase-shift changes the potential and is propagated out in the field because of local symmetry and not global. They write that global symmetry is not possible because of relativity OR THE ELASTICITY OF THE VACUUM. Because this apparently can be explained through the elasticity of the vacuum, I wonder are there other things in gauge symmetry that require special relativity, or could you possibly formulate gauge theory non-relativistically?

I mean can you formulate the phase-shifts and the origin of charge completely non-relativistically?

Comment: Hi So La. Welcome to Phys.SE. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Comment: Could you formulate a theory of gauge fields that was not relativistic? Yes, certainly. Would it be possible to make such a theory match experiments? Nobody has done so as of yet. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I wonder if you can remove special relativity from gauge theory and that this non relativistic theory would work as well as the other at speeds that doesn't approach the speed of light.